# setting query value to null from variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert null values into a database using PDO but seem to be having problems

**code**

```
public function addBookCategory($id, $isbn, $category, $parent){
    $id = $this->dbh->quote($id);
    $isbn = $this->dbh->quote($isbn);
    $category = $this->dbh->quote($category);
    $parent = $this->dbh->quote($parent);

    return $this->query(
        "INSERT INTO book_categories 
        VALUES($id, $isbn, $category, $parent) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = $id"
    );
}
```

There are instances where the parent column can be null however none of the following set parent to null, instead it sets the value to an empty string "" or to a null string "NULL".

```
$database->addBookCategory("kujhg", "asdasd", "asdasd", NULL);
$database->addBookCategory("kujhg", "asdasd", "asdasd", "");
$database->addBookCategory("kujhg", "asdasd", "asdasd", "NULL");
```

What can be done to overcome this problem?

Comment: `NULL` should not be quoted. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: @showdev well I realise that...

Comment: Remove `$parent = $this->dbh->quote($parent);` Or for more flexibility, do this for all of the variables: `$parent = is_null($parent)?$parent:$this->dbh->quote($parent);`

Comment: @showdev It has to be `$parent = is_null($parent) ? "NULL" : $this->dbh->quote($parent);`, quotes have to be avoided

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Inserting `"NULL"` and `NULL` are two different things. You want `NULL`, right?

Comment: The query is just a string after all, the reason it wasn't working properly was because ",NULL)" was being changed to ",'NULL')" when quote was used.

Answer (score 0):

you should write column names

```
   "INSERT INTO book_categories (id, isbn , category,parent)
    VALUES($id, $isbn, $category, $parent) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = $id"
```

and then use this one

```
  $database->addBookCategory("kujhg", "asdasd", "asdasd", NULL);
```